# how to get sum row into xls by xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have a tuple like

```
t = ((a,b,1,2),(a,b,3,4),(a,c,1,3),(c,d,3,6))
```

I used xlwt's wb to write a .xls file. But now I neeed add a sum row below like:

```
 C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
 a | b | 1 | 2
 a | b | 3 | 4
 a | c | 1 | 3
 c | d | 3 | 6
total: | 8 | 15
```

How to do this?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: The [xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) reference is not relevant here, as it is (and can only be) used to *write* .xls files

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, you can use this list comprehension

```py
# assumes all rows have same number of columns

# changes the structure of table
transpose = [[row[i] for row in table] for i in range(len(table[0]))]

# store sum of transpose[-2] and transpose[-1] in total
total = [sum(transpose[i]) for i in range(-2,0)]
```

You will have to change the second line of code according to your needs.